# Chrome Extension Badge - Text Color

Tags: google-chrome-extension

A quick question regarding the Chrome Badge/Browser Action API.
Is there a method to set the badge text colour? (much like you can with the back colour).
I'm sure I remember seeing a reference to a method such as SetBadgeTextColor() somewhere on the Internet (not sure where, mind).

Edit: [Chromium Wiki - Browser Actions Proposal](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/BrowserActions)

The link above is where I saw a method to set the badge text colour. Was this proposal ever implemented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot change the text color directly.

What you *can* do is to paint the base image on a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Canvas_tutorial), then draw the text using your desired color and finally use [`chrome.browserAction.setIcon`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon) to update the badge.

Comment: Well, that's kind of defeat the point of a badge if we have to use canvas, we might as well write text in it...

Answer (score 4):

chrome ext detects badge bg color (light or dark) and set text color automatically (black or white). if your background color is around the boundary of those. try to increase or decrease your bg color code e.g your bg color is red #FF0000 then chrome will detects it as light but when you decrease the color code hex to #FE0000 it will detected as dark, and it's still solid red in our eyes

Comment: This sentence is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MV3, we can finally update badge colors (text and background), using [chrome.action](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/action#parts_of_the_ui)):

```js
chrome.action.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: 'purple' });
chrome.action.setBadgeTextColor({ color: 'white' });
```